# Knockout Binding not happen correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to bind data by knockout but data not binding correctly
I have gotten the data by ajax and put it in self.DisplayItem object successfully
But the problem in Binding only where data not shown in the div

This is javascript code:

```
function CustomItem(prams) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(prams.Id || 0);
    self.Name = ko.observable(prams.Name || "");
    self.Title = ko.observable(prams.Title  || "");
}

function BaseViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.DisplayItem = ko.observable(null);
   
   self.DisplayItem = new CustomItem({
      Id: 0,
      Name : "",
      Title : ""
   });
  
   self.GetDetails = function (Id) {

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: URL + 'Customer/GetDetails/' + Id,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
             self.DisplayItem = new CustomItem(data);
          },
      });

  };

  ko.applyBindings(self);
}
```

Html code:

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.GetDetails">Show Data</button>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
       <div><label class="control-label">Name</label></div>
       <div data-bind="text: DisplayItem.Name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
       <div><label class="control-label">Title</label></div>
       <div data-bind="text: DisplayItem.Title"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No binding happen, the data not show in html div, can you give me solution?

Comment: You never call `GetDetails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the observable functionality by **assigning** to the observable property.

Instead, pass the assigned value to the `function` that the observable property becomes:

```
self.DisplayItem(new CustomItem({
   Id: 0,
   Name : "",
   Title : ""
}));
```

and when you have fetched your data:

```
self.DisplayItem(new CustomItem(data));
```

For reference, see [reading and writing observables](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables).

Comment: did you mean I have to delete this line of code:   self.DisplayItem = ko.observable(null);